# Which programming languages allow default values for method parameters?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm curious which languages allow you to do something like this:

```
method foo(String bar = "beh"){

}
```

If you call foo like this:

```
foo();
```

`bar` will be set to "beh", but if you call like this:

```
foo("baz");
```

`bar` will be set to "baz".

Comment: I think this might be a candidate for communiwikification...

Comment: are you asking for an exhaustive list in one answer or just everyone give their favorite example??

Comment: What I would love would be a single answer that names all languages that do allow this with syntax examples. In retrospect, yes this would be a great candidate for wikification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### [PHP:](http://ideone.com/HtMym)

```
function foo($var = "foo") {
    print $var;
}

foo(); // outputs "foo"
foo("bar"); // outputs "bar"
```

#### [Python](http://ideone.com/PwGnH):

```
def myFun(var = "foo"):
    print var
```

#### [Ruby](http://ideone.com/6lj5W):

```
def foo(var="foo")
    print var
end
```

#### [Groovy:](http://ideone.com/LvXIU)

```
def foo(var="foo") {
    print var
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I'm looking for. The language and then an example in that langauge.

Comment: @Alaor Because this is not by any means an exhaustive list

Answer (score 11):

- almost all Lisps
- Ruby
- Python
- C++
- C#
- Visual Basic.NET
- Tcl
- Visual Basic
- Ioke
- Seph
- Cobra
- Nemerle
- Mirah
- Delphi
- Groovy
- PHP
- Fancy
- Scala

Comment: OCaml has default arguments as well (for named arguments).

Answer (score 8):

Ones I can think of

- C# 4.0
- C++
- VB.Net (all versions)
- VB6
- F# (members only)
- Powershell
- IDL
- Ruby

Answer (score 3):

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org) provides this, as well as keyword arguments:

```
(define (f x [y 0]) (+ x y))
(f 1) ; => 1
(f 10 20) ; => 30

(define (g x #:y [y 0]) (- x y))
(g 1) ; => 1
(g 10 #:y 20) ; => -10
```

They're described in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html#%28part._.Declaring_.Optional_.Arguments%29).

Answer (score 2):

as of c# 4.0 you can now have default params. Finally!

Also C++, Ruby and VB

Answer (score 2):

Delphi has allowed this since about version 5 - released in 1999

```
procedure foo(const bar: string = 'beh');
begin
...
end;

foo;
foo('baz');
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl does with [`Method::Signatures`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Method-Signatures/).

Answer (score 2):

Python:

```
def foo(bar = value):
    # This function can be invoked as foo() or foo(something).
    # In the former case, bar will have its default value.
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

TCL provides this functionality

```
proc procName {{arg1 defaultValue} {arg2 anotherDefaultValue}} {
    # proc body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/function.html):

```
void foo(int x, int y = 3)
{
   ...
}
...
foo(4);   // same as foo(4, 3);
```

[Fantom](http://fantom.org/doc/docIntro/Tour.html):

```
class Person
{
  Int yearsToRetirement(Int retire := 65) { return retire - age }

  Int age
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has a workaround.

You can have the foo method with no parameters that calls the foo method with parameters setting the default value, like this:

```
void foo() {
   foo("beh");
}

void foo(String bar) {
   this.bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: The name for this is method overloading.

Comment: Sure, but since he didn't asked about method overloading, but about method default parameters values, method overloading is a workaround.

Comment: And it's super-fun writing eight overloaded methods to reproduce three defaultable arguments, eh. Especially when Policy demands each needs to have its own lengthy XML javadoc. aaargh.

Comment: I'm not defending Java here. I'm just posting the workaround. And it's not necessary to write 8 methods for 3 default arguments, only 4.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the list Realbasic (indeed Realbasic has almost every nice feature of every language I can think of, including introspection and sandboxed scripting).

Python. (But watch out for mutables per http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm )

And plenty of languages, including C, allow variable numbers of parameters which effectively lets you do the same thing.

In many modern scripting languages, including PHP, JavaScript, and Perl, a better idiom for handling such things is to allow an associative array or object as a parameter, and then assign defaults if needed.

e.g.

```
function foo( options ){
  if( options.something === undefined ){
    options.something = some_default_value;
  }
  ...
}
```

This eliminates the necessity of putting the defaultable values at the end of the list of parameters and remembering all the stuff you don't want to override.

As always -- use in moderation.

Comment: "allow an associative array or object as a parameter" Unless you have a large list of arguments with no consistent usage frequency, this is a horrible idea.

Comment: IIRC, REALbasic started out life as a Visual Basic clone for the Mac.  Given this pedigree, I'll respectfully disagree with your assertion that it "has almost every nice feature of every language".  I won't downvote you, though.

Comment: @NullUserException: if you don't have arbitrary lists of one kind of argument, why is it a horrible idea? It's a simple tradeoff of performance vs. flexibility/robustness/expandability. When coding libraries I frequently find myself regretting not having chosen this approach. @meador RB was never a VB "clone". It was a completely OO language from day one (before VB.NET) which tried to allow relatively easy porting of VB projects. RB has never had the ugliness of VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PL/SQL.

Answer (score -2):

I know Python allows this, while C,C++ don't.